# Elsarticle no bibliography on the pdf output

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, elsarticle

I would like to get some help about the elsaarticle class (http://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0019/166141/elsarticle-template.zip).

When I use bibtex I get a PDF **without** bibliogrpahy...

The compilation I use is:

```
pdflatex elsarticle-template
bibtex mybibfile
pdflatex elsarticle-template
pdflatex elsarticle-template
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve that issue. I tried to check on the internet but I find no solution and I strugle for more than 1h on this problem... I'm a Win7 user with MikTeX distrib.

The original `elsarticle-template.tex` file is:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Elsevier bibliography styles
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% To change the style, put a % in front of the second line of the current style and
%% remove the % from the second line of the style you would like to use.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
%\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Elsevier \LaTeX\ template\tnoteref{mytitlenote}}
\tnotetext[mytitlenote]{Fully documented templates are available in the elsarticle package on \href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle}{CTAN}.}

%% Group authors per affiliation:
\author{Elsevier\fnref{myfootnote}}
\address{Radarweg 29, Amsterdam}
\fntext[myfootnote]{Since 1880.}

%% or include affiliations in footnotes:
\author[mymainaddress,mysecondaryaddress]{Elsevier Inc}
\ead[url]{www.elsevier.com}

\author[mysecondaryaddress]{Global Customer Service\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{support@elsevier.com}

\address[mymainaddress]{1600 John F Kennedy Boulevard, Philadelphia}
\address[mysecondaryaddress]{360 Park Avenue South, New York}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here...
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
\texttt{elsarticle.cls}\sep \LaTeX\sep Elsevier \sep template
\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers

\section{The Elsevier article class}

\paragraph{Installation} If the document class \emph{elsarticle} is not available on your computer, you can download and install the system package \emph{texlive-publishers} (Linux) or install the \LaTeX\ package \emph{elsarticle} using the package manager of your \TeX\ installation, which is typically \TeX\ Live or Mik\TeX.

\paragraph{Usage} Once the package is properly installed, you can use the document class \emph{elsarticle} to create a manuscript. Please make sure that your manuscript follows the guidelines in the Guide for Authors of the relevant journal. It is not necessary to typeset your manuscript in exactly the same way as an article, unless you are submitting to a camera-ready copy (CRC) journal.

\paragraph{Functionality} The Elsevier article class is based on the standard article class and supports almost all of the functionality of that class. In addition, it features commands and options to format the
\begin{itemize}
\item document style
\item baselineskip
\item front matter
\item keywords and MSC codes
\item theorems, definitions and proofs
\item lables of enumerations
\item citation style and labeling.
\end{itemize}

\section{Front matter}

The author names and affiliations could be formatted in two ways:
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item Group the authors per affiliation.
\item Use footnotes to indicate the affiliations.
\end{enumerate}
See the front matter of this document for examples. You are recommended to conform your choice to the journal you are submitting to.

\section{Bibliography styles}

There are various bibliography styles available. You can select the style of your choice in the preamble of this document. These styles are Elsevier styles based on standard styles like Harvard and Vancouver. Please use Bib\TeX\ to generate your bibliography and include DOIs whenever available.

Here are two sample references: \cite{Feynman1963118,Dirac1953888}.

\section*{References}




\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

The original `mybibfile.bib` reference file is:

```
@article{Dirac1953888,
  title   = "The lorentz transformation and absolute time",
  journal = "Physica ",
  volume  = "19",
  number  = "1-–12",
  pages   = "888--896",
  year    = "1953",
  doi     = "10.1016/S0031-8914(53)80099-6",
  author  = "P.A.M. Dirac"
}

@article{Feynman1963118,
  title   = "The theory of a general quantum system interacting with a linear dissipative system",
  journal = "Annals of Physics ",
  volume  = "24",
  pages   = "118--173",
  year    = "1963",
  doi     = "10.1016/0003-4916(63)90068-X",
  author  = "R.P Feynman and F.L {Vernon Jr.}"
}
```

[image]

Comment: `bibtex elsarticle-template`, not `bibtex mybibfile`.

Comment: @IanThompson It does not work either.

Comment: It works for me. What is the output in the terminal when you run bibtex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution it was reatex to the line

```
\bibliographystyle{model2-names.bst}\biboptions{authoryear}
```

So the compilation works by **removing** the .bst

```
\bibliographystyle{model2-names}\biboptions{authoryear}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also had the same problem (Win7, MikTeX), and solved it by configuring Texmaker. First, Click the Options menu

```
Options > Configure Texmaker > Quick Build
```

choose the option

```
PdflaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdflaTeX (x2) + View Pdf
```

[image: Configuration steps]

Comment: How does this solve the problem? The O.P. already stated that he/she does `pdflatex` etc. twice, with `biblatex`. Where's the connection of TeXMaker to the question?

Comment: If you use and configure the Quick Build option as above, TeXMaker automatically will compile `bibtex elsarticle-template` instead of `bibtex mybibfile` as @IanThompson said. His solution worked for me too.